# != is not funtioning properly in while loop

Tags: java, while-loop

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class piglatin{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("enter a string");
        String s=in.nextLine(),n1="",n2="",n3="";
        int i;
        for(i=0;i<s.length();i++){
            if(s.charAt(i)=='a'||s.charAt(i)=='e'||s.charAt(i)=='o'||s.charAt(i)=='i'||s.charAt(i)=='u')
                while (s.charAt(i)!=' '&& i!=s.length()){     // hre lies the problem
                    n1+=s.charAt(i);
                    i++;
                }
            else if(s.charAt(i)==' '){
                n2="";
                i++;
            }
            else
                n2+=s.charAt(i);

            n3=n3+n1+n2+"ay ";


        }
        System.out.println(n3);
    }
}
```

here when i matches the value of length the loop should break but it always show outofbounds exception. what is my mistake i have used && and the gateway should give false && true = false
please help

Comment: Swap the expressions that `i != s.length()` is checked before `s.charAt(i)` is calculated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your last iteration `while (s.charAt(i)!=' '&& i!=s.length()){`

It tries to grab `s.charAt(i)` causing an `IndexOutOfBounds`, because `i = length` meaning that is one value to high for the size of the array.

If you check the size first it will evaluate to be not true because `i = length` so you will never reach the `s.charAt(i)` because the first evaluation will not be true, thus never throwing the exception. This is called short circuiting.

Answer (score 0):

the fuses defining your condition are wrong!

```
if(s.charAt(i)=='a'|| s.charAt(i)=='e'|| 
   s.charAt(i)=='o'|| s.charAt(i)=='i'|| s.charAt(i)=='u')
       
    while (s.charAt(i) != ' ' && i!=s.length()){     // hre lies the problem
        n1+=s.charAt(i);
        i++;
    }
```

if the char is a or e, i, o or u then why check `s.charAt(i) != ' '`??
on the other hand,
if you do a for like this

```
for(i=0;i<s.length();i++){
```

where i will never reach the `s.length` why do u do: `i!=s.length()`

that while condition is just dead code

Comment: In theory it could be a space, because he is incrementing in the array in the while loop so there could be different values that we don't know about.

Comment: nope... "IF is a vowel" is not possible to be a space...

Comment: `while (i != s.length() &&s.charAt(i) !=' ')`  length should be checked first.

Comment: He only check the char at `i` is 'c' say it is at index 0,  it goes into the loop which increments to the next `i` which would be index 1 since we can't see the array we don't know what the next value at the index is

Answer (score 0):

Change your while condition to this :

```
while (i != s.length() && s.charAt(i) !=' ')
```

You should check the length first before charAt(i)